# "escapeshellcmd() has been disabled for security reasons" octobercms while sending wmails

Tags: email, security, hosting, octobercms

I'm having problems with my hesting which I cannot change by now.

I'm getting "escapeshellcmd() has been disabled for security reasons" while sending mails using PHPMAIl option.

I need to find alternative for phpmail since I cannot change hosting right now.

Comment: Use the SMTP method in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use the built in [Php mail function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). You can also use a third party library such as [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/). Another option is to use a third party email service such as Spark Post or Mailgun.